# Are there any plugins/npm's /methods that allows me to let user to use his master card or debit (bank) card in ionic?

Tags: ionic2, payment

I want to ask if there are any methods/ plugins/ npm's that allows me to let users use there payments card such as master card or debit cards in ionic !

I searched about this topic and I could find two useful links

First: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/paypal/

Second: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/stripe/

But still I didn't use/test them before asks to make sure are these plugin support master/debit cards or not ?

If not, how can I use payment service in java/typescript of ionic ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For- https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/paypal/

[Paypal plugin](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin) 
are now Deprecated and only existing integrations are supported. For all new integrations, use [Braintree Direct](https://www.braintreepayments.com/products/braintree-direct) in supported countries. In other countries, use [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/accept-payments/express-checkout/ec-braintree-sdk/get-started/) and choose the Braintree SDK integration option.

In ionic use braintree native - https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/braintree/
(Braintree is a division of PayPal)

and also you can use other third party service of braintree.